# Why I cannot ping local IPs on my Mac?

Tags: macos, networking, ip, ping

I'm trying to ping local IPs on my Mac but it's not working as I would expect.

If I ping 127.0.0.1, there's no problem:

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
```

However if I ping any other local IPs, it doesn't work:

```
PING 127.0.0.99 (127.0.0.99): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

If I try the same thing on Windows, it's working. Does anybody know why it is not working on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a solution - you have to create an alias to be able to ping it.

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.99 up
```

As for why it's not working, seems that Apple decided to implement just a 127.0.0.1, not a 127.0.0.0/8 subnet.

See also [How do you get loopback addresses other than 127.0.0.1 to work on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/458875/how-do-you-get-loopback-addresses-other-than-127-0-0-1-to-work-on-os-x)