# redirect 127.0.0.2:80 to 127.0.0.1:3000 using pfctl

Tags: networking, macos, osx-yosemite, pf

**Background**

I'm trying to make a redirection setup to make it so that when I make a request to `example.com` it would be redirected to `127.0.0.1:3000`.

I know that I can map `example.com` to `127.0.0.2` via `/etc/hosts`. Now I want to route `127.0.0.2:80` to `127.0.0.1:3000`.

**The problem**

I'm using pfctl (that is default on Yosemite). There is the rule that I try to use:

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.2 to 127.0.0.2 port http -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I get timeout when trying to reach `127.0.0.2`.

Comment: See [How do you get loopback addresses other than 127.0.0.1 to work on OS X](http://superuser.com/q/458875/615410).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your source address isn't `127.0.0.2`. `ifconfig lo0` will show you your source address upon going toward the `127/8` network.

Then I would suggest you to change your `rdr` rule to a larger one:

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.2 port http -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
```